# Mat Auto Complete does not open dropdown panel after clicking Clear button

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular11, mat-autocomplete

I have custom Mat Auto Complete in Angular project. It has 2 suffixes, Clear and Dropdown buttons. When I click on clear button code `this.myControl.reset('', { emitEvent: true });` resets the input value. But the dropdown panel does not open. I tried to use following formats and none worked

1. this.myControl.reset();
2. this.myControl.reset('', { emitEvent: true });
3. this.myControl.patchValue('');

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tivwi8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts)

**autocomplete-display-example.ts**

```
.......

 clearInput() {
    this.arrowIcon = "arrow_drop_down";
    this.myControl.reset('', { emitEvent: true });
  }

......
```

**autocomplete-display-example.html**

```
<form class="example-form">
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
   <input
     type="text"
     matInput
     [formControl]="myControl"
     [matAutocomplete]="auto"

   />
   <div matSuffix style="display:flex">
     <button
       *ngIf="myControl!==undefined && myControl.value!==null && myControl?.value!==''"
       mat-icon-button
       aria-label="Clear"
       (click)="clearInput()"
       type="button"
     >
       <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
     </button>

     <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" type="button">
       <mat-icon>{{arrowIcon}}</mat-icon>
     </button>
   </div>

   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (opened)="arrowIcon='arrow_drop_up'"
     (closed)="arrowIcon='arrow_drop_down'" (optionSelected)="arrowIcon='arrow_drop_down'">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
       {{option.name}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>

<!-- Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
   Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
   can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, when I click on Clear icon, it resets the form control and also closes the panel. To fix this we can open the panel manually. Inject the `MatAutocompleteTrigger` to the method along with `event`

See the updated [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-mat-auto-complete?file=src/app/autocomplete-display-example.html).

```
  openPanel(evt: any, trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger): void {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.myControl?.reset();
    trigger.openPanel();
    this.inputAutoComplete?.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Add  `#trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"` to the input and pass this to button `click()` method

**autocomplete-display-example.html**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
    <input #inputAutoComplete
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"
           matInput
           type="text"
    />

    <div matSuffix style="display:flex">
      <button
        (click)="openPanel($event, trigger)"
        *ngIf=" myControl?.value!==null && myControl?.value!==''"
        aria-label="Clear"
        mat-icon-button
        type="button"
      >
        <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <button aria-label="Clear" mat-icon-button type="button">
        <mat-icon>{{arrowIconSubject.getValue()}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (closed)="arrowIconSubject.next('arrow_drop_down')"
      (opened)="arrowIconSubject.next('arrow_drop_up')" (optionSelected)="arrowIconSubject.next('arrow_drop_down')"
      [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async " [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Your StackBlitz saved me, this a problem I tried to solve for 8-10 hours!! You're my hero of the week :)

Comment: @Itay I am glad it helped you. Still don't know why such basic feature is not supported in official material components

Comment: BTW, if I delete the ```evt.stopPropagation();``` and put the ```focus()``` and ```openPane()``` in a ```setTimout``` with zero seconds it also works.. it's interesting.

Comment: And ```requestAnimationFrame``` instead of ```setTimeout()``` will also do the same :)

Comment: @Itay Since I need to use this in multiple projects, I created new library for this. You can see it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngxsmart/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Call the filtered function after the date is received. IF the data is local then call filter function after the date is declared and if the data is coming from **Rest api** then exactly after success response call the filter function Like this

```
private getAllCategories() {
this.categoryService.getCategory("").subscribe(
     (response) => {
         if (response) {
             this.categories = response['rows'];


            //Now callling category filter after data is received

            this.filteredCategories = this.category.valueChanges
            .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(state => state ? this._filterCateg(state) : this.categories?.slice())
            );
         }
     },
     (error) => {
         console.info('error:', error);
             }
 );
}
```

It worked for me!